# Documentation for ArcPy site-package?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, documentation

Has anyone found any informative documentation about Esri's ArcPy Python module?

Comment: Because this is turning into a (useful) list-of-things thread, without much prospect for a single objectively good answer, it is ideal for CW status: "Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion."

Answer (score 17):

[ESRI's own documentation is pretty good.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html?v=3&q=arcpy.mapping#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/)

Comment: I don't like that they don't have an object model diagram though, like they used to with 9.3...

Comment: I agree.  I've used the 9.3 object model diagram quite a bit in my scripting projects.  I asked an ESRI rep whether a similar diagram would be available for ArcPy in version 10, and he said he doubted it.  Too bad, because a high level overview is really helpful when learning a new library.

Comment: An Enhancement has been logged requesting an OMD for Arcpy/geoproceesing with the number:  
[NIM050896](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/nimbus-bug?bugID=TklNMDUwODk2 "Link to NIM")

Answer (score 9):

Here is a list of references I have started to put together for myself:

[ArcGIS 10 and Python](http://gisweb.apsu.edu/blogs/arcgis-10-and-python)

Answer (score 6):

Not documentation, but a colleague just passed [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/VirtualGISClassroom/GIS%20Programming%20101%20ArcGIS%2010/The%20ArcPy%20Mapping%20Module/player.html) along.

Answer (score 5):

Have a try here : [ArcGIS 10.1 arcpy Wall Reference Poster](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=20b26b39913c4661a2ba85674d07c2e3)

Answer (score 2):

I like this OMD if anyone is interested:

[ArcGIS 10.0 OMD](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/50806-ArcPy-Geoprocessor-OMD-v10-Unofficial)

Answer (score 1):

See this [url](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008EIeAAM) from the ArcGIS Idea page

ESRI responsded with the following:

> Thank you for posting the idea along with all your comments for why you feel the OMD is particularly valuable in your work. There are a few reasons we have chosen not to produce object model diagrams for the ArcPy site package. Traditionally Python’s own modules and other 3rd party site packages do not carry Object Model Diagrams. An OMD was provided with arcgisscripting to help customers comfortable with ArcObjects and its Object Model Diagram make the transition to Python. At ArcGIS 10, ArcPy was more than just a name change; it was a change in the way we organized and presented our python implementation, something that is more in line with the idea of a true Python site-package. In addition, major efforts have been made to improve the help for Python at ArcGIS 10. With arcgisscripting, there was limited intellisense and doc strings, so without some visual help directly in front of you, it was very difficult to know what functions and properties existed. The help is also better structured in ArcGIS 10.0 under the topic ‘The ArcPy Site-package’ with a list of all the functions and classes and embedded links between related topics. With these improvements to the documentation and built-in help within Python we believe all the resources are in place to successfully navigate ArcPy.